# Custom Directives in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a navbar whenever we click on a country name the respective map should appear on the screen .

As of now , the country coordinates are hard coded into the directive I built. But I am not able to make directive displayed on the screen.

I know , I am missing something very basic but I could not figure it out till now.

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to the world of directives!</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ng-repeat="countryTab in countries" ng-click="itemClicked(countryTab.label)" style="cursor:pointer">
                    <a>{{countryTab.label}}</a>
                    <country-tab-bar country="selectedCountry"></country-tab-bar>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app',[]);
        app.controller('appCtrl',function($scope){
            $scope.countries = [{
              id: 1,
              label: 'Italy',
              coords: '41.29246,12.5736108'
            }, {
              id: 2,
              label: 'Japan',
              coords: '37.4900318,136.4664008'
            }, {
              id: 3,
              label: 'USA',
              coords: '37.6,-95.665'
            }, {
              id: 4,
              label: 'India',
              coords: '20.5937,78.9629'
            }];
        });

        app.directive('countryTabBar',function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope:{
                    country: '='
                },
                template: '<div>'+
                '   <div>Italy</div>'+
                '   <br/>'+
                '   <img ng-src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={{country.coords}}&zoom=4&size=800x200"> '+        
                '</div>',
                link : function(scope,elem,attrs){
                    scope.itemClicked = function(value){
                        scope.selectedCountry = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Nothing happens when I click on the country names . Also the UI is screwed up.

[image]

What is the basic thing that I am missing ?

Please give an explanation for the same. I am pretty much new to Angular.

Comment: your itemClicked function does nothing, looking at the code it seems you want it to do nothing? Are you trying to do something on the parent controller when the directive is clicked?

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand ..to show the directive and the directive shows the coordinates and the google image of Italy as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You directive tag will look something like below, which expect selected country.

```
<div ng-if="selectedCountry">
    <country-tab-bar country="selectedCountry"></country-tab-bar>
<div>
```

then have `itemClicked` inside a controller which will have `selectedCountry`

```
scope.itemClicked = function(value){
   $scope.selectedCountry = value;
}
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('countryTabBar',function(){
    return {
        restrict: ';E',
        templateUrl: 'countryDirective.tpl.html',
        scope : {
           country: '='
        }
    }
});
```

**countryDirective.tpl.html**

```
<div>
    <div>{{country.label}}</div>
    <img ng-src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={{country.coords}}&zoom=4&size=800x200">         
</div>
```

Comment: @StrugglingCoder have you tried what I've suggested?

Comment: Could you please explain what is the `city` in the `scope` object and what exactly are you trying to do in the link function ?

Comment: Apologies, that was typo, it should be `country` and that would be taken from directive `country` attribute

Comment: @StrugglingCoder could you provide me a plunker?