# Passing argument to custom directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `navbar` that shows few `country names` and when you click on them respective `map` should show up.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to the world of directives!</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ng-repeat="countryTab in countries" ng-clicked="itemClicked(countryTab)" style="cursor:pointer">
                <a>{{countryTab.label}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And the `array of countries` for now is hard-coded .

```
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('appCtrl',function($scope){
         // Countries
        $scope.countries = [{
          id: 1,
          label: 'Italy',
          coords: '41.29246,12.5736108'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          label: 'Japan',
          coords: '37.4900318,136.4664008'
        }, {
          id: 3,
          label: 'USA',
          coords: '37.6,-95.665'
        }, {
          id: 4,
          label: 'India',
          coords: '20.5937,78.9629'
        }];
    });
```

The `custom directive` that should show the respective map for now is like :

```
<div>
    <country-tab-bar></country-tab-bar>
</div>
```

And

```
    app.directive('countryTabBar',function(){
        return {
            restrict: ';E',
            template: '<div>'+
                            '   <div>Italy</div>'+
                            '   <br/>'+
                            '   <img ng-src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=41.29246,12.5736108&zoom=4&size=800x200"> '+        
                            '</div>',
            link : function(scope){
                scope.itemClicked = function(value){
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

`As it is hard coded coordinates , it only shows one map of Italy. But I want to make it to show respective maps passing coordinates .`

Also the name in the `div` should change to reflect **the current country** .

[image]

How to achieve the same ?

Please provide a necessary explanation.

Comment: Its similar to your last question, haven't you looked at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41207875/2435473) provided by me(I guess probably that would solve your problem).. You shouldn't be asking same question multiple times for no reason..

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks a lot . Could you please explain what is the `city` in the `scope` object and what exactly are you trying to do in the link function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired like below

you need to pass the country label and country coords from the html to directive first.

```
<country-tab-bar coords="countryTab.coords" country="countryTab.label"></country-tab-bar>
```

Receive the values in directive scope.

```
        scope: {
           coords: '=coords',
           country: '=country',
        }
```

in the link section use these scope members and update the template URL. append this to the element (this is the html tag where the directive is applied). and finally compile it.

```js
 var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('appCtrl',function($scope){
         // Countries
        $scope.countries = [{
          id: 1,
          label: 'Italy',
          coords: '41.29246,12.5736108'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          label: 'Japan',
          coords: '37.4900318,136.4664008'
        }, {
          id: 3,
          label: 'USA',
          coords: '37.6,-95.665'
        }, {
          id: 4,
          label: 'India',
          coords: '20.5937,78.9629'
        }];
    });

app.directive('countryTabBar', function($compile){
        return {
            restrict: ';E',
            scope: {
            coords: '=coords',
            country: '=country',
            },
            link : function(scope,element){
              
              var template = '<div ng-click="show()">'+scope.country+'</div><img ng-src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='+scope.coords+'&zoom=4&size=800x200">'; 
              
            element.append(template);
              
           $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                
            }
        }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to the world of directives!</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ng-repeat="countryTab in countries"  style="cursor:pointer">
          
             <country-tab-bar coords="countryTab.coords" country="countryTab.label"></country-tab-bar>
          
          </li>
          
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
```